# Insert &nbsp; in Rails with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, typography

i need to insert nbsp symbol in some places of the HTML, that comes from DB and will be displayed on the page.

I do following:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML( self.content )
doc.css("p").each do |p|
    p.content.gsub! pattern, "&nbsp;"
end
```

This resulting text contains nbsp, displayed as a plain text, but not a special symbol.

I also tried to use following:

```
p.content.gsub! pattern, "\u00A0"
p.content.gsub! pattern, "&#160;"
p.content.gsub! pattern, 160.chr # paragraph disappears in this case
p.content.gsub! pattern, "\240"  # paragraph disappears in this case
```

But they all do not work.

It seems, like "content" methods of Nokogiri node escapes special symbols, while modifiying the content or inner_text.

Is there any way to access raw node content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing - maybe `p.content.gsub! pattern, "&nbsp;".html_safe` may help?

Comment: Wow! Amazing solution! Much better, than using CGI.unescapeHTML(...) ! Thanks a lot, man !